# Is it possible to run PHP include() inside an echo?

Tags: php

Is this possible to include an external file inside an echo?

This is what I am trying:

```
    echo 'stuff'.(include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/theme/button.php')).'morestuff';
```

I could simply write 3 lines but I wanted to know for simplification purposes.

Comment: "I could simply write 3 lines but I wanted to know for simplification purposes." 3 lines **is** the simple version. Don't overcomplicate things (and sacrifice usability while you're at it).

Comment: Yeah, you do! Since the file that you requiring be a single string output (*. Txt, *. php, whatever). However, this approach should be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  `echo` implicity calls `__toString()` on whatever is contained within the statement to be `echo`'d.

What you should do is `include` the file and have the HTML in the included file.  No need to echo.

Comment: nobody provided a working method to do it. I assume this is the correct answer so far

Answer (score 3):

You should just use `include`.

```
<div>
<?php include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/theme/snippets/follow-button.php'; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't do the same thing. His original uses what the include file _returns_, yours requires the include file to _echo_ something.

Comment: @Barmar Yep, this depends on the content of that script.

Answer (score 2):

I tested this and it works...  I only put HTML code in the 'button.php' file...

```
echo 'stuff'; include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/theme/button.php'); echo 'morestuff';
```

Comment: This would be the correct way to go about it. This also works with `require`.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can. If the included file is returning anything, that will be printed. Includes basically evaluate the file and can be used as a normal function.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be cleaner for the include file to define a function that returns the value you want. Then you would do:

```
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/theme/button.php');
echo echo 'stuff'.button_func().'morestuff';
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to do this. Just break the echo. Example below...

```
<?php
echo "
  $value1 <div id='1'></div>
  $value2 <div id='2'></div>
  // I want my include here
  $value3 <div id='3'></div>
";
?>
```

Change above to;

```
<?php
echo "
  $value1 <div id='1'></div>
  $value2 <div id='2'></div>
";
  include 'some_file.php';
echo "
  $value3 <div id='3'></div>
";
?>
```